# How to push json data in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json file, the file have data like this format :

```
{
    "rigidBodies": [
        {
            "name": "ball1.png", "imagePath": "ball1.png", "origin": {"x": 0, "y": 0},
            "polygons": [
                [
                    {"x": 0.16999998688697815, "y": 0.5724999904632568},
                    {"x": 0.16749995946884155, "y": 0.5324999690055847},
                    {"x": 0.16999998688697815, "y": 0.45250001549720764}
                ],
                [
                    {"x": 0.16999998688697815, "y": 0.45250001549720764},
                    {"x": 0.16749995946884155, "y": 0.375},
                    {"x": 0.2199999988079071, "y": 0.3725000023841858}
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to push the data in an Array so I have tried this way and it says error,

```
var poly = new Array();

    // note : parsing json 
    $.getJSON('my_assets/addPhysics/testPhysics.json', function(data) {
        //do stuff with your data here
             $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                   // for(var i=0;i<item[0].length;i++){
                        poly.push(item[0][i].x,item[0][i].y);
                    //}  
             });
    });
```

---

Comment: data is not array, it is object

Comment: so how can get the 'x' and 'y' of my json file and push into Array ?

Comment: question is not clear. do you want only first object of rigidBodies array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is an object, the array you want to loop through is in the `polygons` property inside the `rigidBodies` array. You need to do:

```js
var data = {
  "rigidBodies": [{
    "name": "ball1.png",
    "imagePath": "ball1.png",
    "origin": {
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0
    },
    "polygons": [
      [{
        "x": 0.16999998688697815,
        "y": 0.5724999904632568
      }, {
        "x": 0.16749995946884155,
        "y": 0.5324999690055847
      }, {
        "x": 0.16999998688697815,
        "y": 0.45250001549720764
      }],
      [{
        "x": 0.16999998688697815,
        "y": 0.45250001549720764
      }, {
        "x": 0.16749995946884155,
        "y": 0.375
      }, {
        "x": 0.2199999988079071,
        "y": 0.3725000023841858
      }]
    ]
  }]
}
var poly = [];

$.each(data.rigidBodies, function(i, body) {
  $.each(body.polygons, function(j, polygon) {
    $.each(polygon, function(k, coords) {
      poly.push([coords.x, coords.y]);
    });
  });
});

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(poly);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: in the second line should be - $.each(body.polygons, function(j, item){//do something} otherwise its showing an error .

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that

Comment: I just noticed that the array is empty I was trying to print the array in console and its printing nothing any idea  ?

Comment: Now that you've formatted the JSON readably, I see that `polygons` is a 2-dimensional array. So another level of `$.each` is needed.

Comment: can you please answer the question with the full solution code .

Comment: Could you show what the desired final result should be? I assume you don't want all the `x` and `y` values from each polygon to be in one array.

Comment: I want **x** and **y** both in my array then it should be 2d array . like this format : poly.push(polygons[0][i].x, polygons[0][i].y);

Comment: how can **data** get **json** file's values in js file ? should I copy the json values in data in my js file  ?

Comment: That's what `$.getJSON` does.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

 `poly.push([item[0][i].x,item[0][i].y]);`

So poly[0][0] is X 
and poly [0][1] is Y